# what is the least privilege needed for data factory

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-data-factory

I am copying data from on-premise to azure data warehouse. I have set up SQL authentication account for data factory with db_writer, db_reader roles and ddladmin roles for that account. When I execute the job it fails, if i assign db_owner to the account then it succeeds. What is the least privilege we should give to data factory account?

i am not convinced db_owner is the right level.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This link may be helpful:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I'd love to know the answer for this.

Comment: You'd need to show the error in order to start troubleshooting.